# how to get most repeated letters from input user?

Tags: r

```
a <- as.character(readline(" Please input a text:    "))

most_repeated_character <- function(x) {
  a <- gsub("\\s+", "", a)
  lets <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
  tbl <- sort(table(lets), decreasing=TRUE)
  print(paste("most frequently occurring: (", names(tbl)[1], ", ", tbl[[1]], ")"))
  print(paste("second most frequently occurring: (", names(tbl)[2], ", ", tbl[[2]], 
")"))
}
most_repeated_character(a)
```

I just want to get the most repeated letters, not characters. So for example if I input "Hello world &&&&", I will get 'l' as the most repeated, not '&'.

Comment: tip: Don't create too many variables, remember that R loads all objects into RAM, which can slow down your computer.

Comment: When dealing with `regex`, it is useful to specify both the desired result and the undesired to avoid misunderstanding, which is just to say `ll` not `&&&&`. I like your `table` approach and will investigate as I would have imagined an `rle`, as 'repeated' tends to suggest 'in a row' whereas table yields number that occurred in any order. Also, readline() returns character so as.character( isn't needed, though not harmful. The suggested [^a-zA-Z] suggested below eliminate both & type things and spaces.

Answer (score 3):

### Use the regular expression for non-alphabet characters.

The regular expression for non-alphabet characters would be `[^a-zA-Z]`.

Try changing:

```
a <- gsub("\\s+", "", a)
```

to:

```
a <- gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible error that you could have is, when you enter **uppercase** and/or **lowercase** words, then, first you have to standardize the inputs, using the functions as: `tolower()` or `toupper()`.

```
librabry(tidyverse)

a <- "HolA MaMA &&&& $$$$ %%%%"

most_repeated_character <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", x) %>% 
    tolower() %>% 
    strsplit("") %>% 
    table() %>% 
    sort(decreasing = TRUE)
  
    print(paste("most frequently occurring: (", names(x)[1], ", ", x[[1]], ")"))
    print(paste("second most frequently occurring: (", names(x)[2], ", ", x[[2]], ")"))
}
most_repeated_character(a)
```